# Calling get_post_meta with custom fields in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to enter a small piece of information that is created from a plugin to an area of my wordpress page that is called my a custom post.

The plugin that I'm using is FlippingBook WordPress Gallery Plugin  (I have purchased a license)

After I create a book I put this code into my post:  [book id='2' /]  This works fine if I just place it in my post, but all of the other content of the page is entered via custom posts so this needs to be as well so it flows inline with the structure of the document.

So I am calling to enter this information like this:

```
        <div>
        <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'enter_page_flip_id', true); ?>
        </div>
```

But the `[book id='2' /]`  no longer renders the book content, only text shows.  Am I writing the custom post call incorrect?

The site:  http://www.cicadabooks.co.uk/new/graphic-book-one/

Thanks much!

Answer (score 2):

The Wordpress function to expand [shortcodes] into HTML is called `do_shortcode`. Try doing `echo do_shortcode(get_post_meta(...))` and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that printing values from `get_post_meta` is different from calling `the_content` or some other built-in for displaying a post body. Those functions look for registered filters on their content and run those filters, which is how a plugin can find its shortcodes like `[book]` to replace.

One thing you might do is read the source of this plugin, find the code that replaces the shortcodes, and call that yourself from your template.

Comment: All of the source code is somehow locked or jumbled so I can't view  the php.  Thanks for the suggestion though.